# AngularJS $UibModal triggering [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'll keep this short.
I'm very new to angularjs and I'm following one of Pluralsights tutorials.

Since the release of the tutorial there are many deprecated built ins that are driving me nuts.

I'm trying to use the following code

```
angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
function ($scope, $location, $uibModal, DataService) {
    $scope.showCreateEmployeeForm = function () {
        //$location.path('/newEmployeeForm');            

        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html',
            controller: 'efController'
        });
    })
```

The tutorial is showing to use $modal (which is now deprecated)... I've tried just using $uibModal instead, and when clicking the button, the event is not firing and I'm getting the following error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24animateCssProvider%20%3C-%20%24animateCss%20%3C-%20%24uibModalStack%20%3C-%20%24uibModal

Oh - I also installed angular using NuGet so I have the latest release

Answer (score 1):

The `animateCssProvider` is only available for angular 1.4+, and you're using 1.3.

From bootstrap UI website:

> AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.4.x or higher, tested with 1.5.3).
>   0.14.3 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.3.x and 0.12.0 is the last version that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.

Just update your angular version.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, thanks for the quick response... I added angularIntellisense to the project and that down downgraded my angular version...

Comment: Welcome. Good luck with the intellisense.